# Подключение библиотеки GL/glut.h под C++ в Eclipse (Ubuntu 12.04, 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu, eclipse, c++, opengl

Добрый день!

Для работы с графикой в С++ есть намерние подключить библиотеку GL/glut.h.
С этой целью были установлены пакеты freeglut3, freeglut3-dev, freeglut3-dbg (через synaptic, так как в терминале было сообщение о конфликте версий).

В общем, файл `/usr/include/GL/glut.h` присутствует, и в свойствах проекта указан соответствующий путь к библиотеке. 
Eclipse, при ее подключении, не ругается и ведет себя адекватно.

Однако возле каждой используемой функции выводится пометка об ошибке и сообщение при компиляции с кучей однообразных ошибок: `undefined reference to '<название функции>'`.

Склоняюсь к версии, что проблема связана с конфликтом версий пакета библиотек OpenGL или c компилятором. Однако пока не совсем представляю, как решить данную проблему.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался, какие есть альтернативы решения данного вопроса?

Comment: Меня интересует, как подключить glut в NetBeans, но механизм и причина ошибок скорее всего общие.

Если бы ещё был представлен шаблон простого приложения - было бы замечательно.

Comment: Вот здесь для C пример подключения библиотек есть http://kiwwito.com/installing-opengl-glut-libraries-in-ubuntu/. В комментариях был рецепт для файла test.c: `gcc test.c -o test -lGL -lglut && gcc -o test test.c -lglut -lGL -lGLU && ./test`. Для g++ рецепт схожий: `g++ main.cpp -o test -lGL -lglut && g++ -o test main.cpp -lglut -lGL -lGLU && ./test`. Как бы заставить NetBeans (или Eclipse, для автора поста) всё это делать вместо меня?

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте к опциям линкера `-lGL` `-lGLU` `-lglut`

В `NetBeans`:

1. <kbd>Run</kbd>-><kbd>Set Project Configuration</kbd>-><kbd>Customize</kbd>-><kbd>Linker</kbd>-><kbd>Additional Options</kbd>. Туда прописываете `-lGlut` `-lGL` `-lGLU`
2. Перекомпилировать проект

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас выдаёт ошибку, что Glut не найден: `g++ -lGlut -lGL -lGLU    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGlut`. Перед этим я ставил `sudo apt-get install freeglut3 freeglut3-dev`. glut.h нашёл в `/usr/include/GL/glut.h`, заинклюдил в main.cpp.

Comment: @dimxenon попробуйте такие опции поставить -lGL -lGLU -lglut. похоже регистр в lglut имеет значение

Comment: Сделано. Похоже, нужно как-то изменит шаблон компиляции в NetBeans. NB делает так: `g++ -lGL -lGLU -lglut    -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o `. Т.е. не указывает кого скомпилировать даже. По мейкфайлам посмотрел, но пока не нашёл, где шаблон сменить.

Comment: @dimxenon он сам должен скомпилировать. Должно работать. Или то же самое показывает?

Comment: Да, то же самое показывает. В принципе, я нашёл как это всё можно компилировать через командную строку. (см. комментарии к топику), хотелось бы просто уже настроить правильно NetBeans, чтобы не переключаться на консоль каждый раз.

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо за старания.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41395/discussion-between-herrgott-and-dimxenon).

Answer (score 0):

**Для Eclypse** всё оказалось просто:

1. Правой кнопкой по проекту -> Properties.
2. Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Miscellaneous: в Other flags 
   дописываем "-lglut -lGL -lGLU" после всех уже присутствующих опций.
3. Tool Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Libraries: нажимаем кнопку с изображением страницы и зелёного плюса, пишем `GL`, нажимаем ОК, так же делаем для `GLU` и `glut`.
4. В окошке Properties for [ИмяПроекта] (где мы и находимся) нажимаем Apply, затем OK.
5. Компилируем.
6. Запускаем.

Готово!

**Для NetBeans:**

Я пока выяснил (опытным путём) как должно быть:
Сначала создаются объектныее файлы (так NetBeans и делает):

```
g++ -lGL -lGLU -lglut -c -g -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
```

Потом рабочее приложение:

```
g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication main.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

Но вместо последнего шага NB делает так: `g++ -lGL -lGLU -lglut -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o`

И получаются ошибки.

Пока что нашёл решение в виде "грязного хака": прописал в дополнительных параметрах `-o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication main.cpp -lGL -lGLU -lglut; echo`. И всё стало нормально компилироваться в NetBeans.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке, в пути `dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/cppapplication` cppapplication - это имя Вашего исполняемого файла. Обычно совпадает с именем проекта в нижнем регистре. `main.cpp` - это главный исходник в проекте.

**Решение временное, не элегантное, но работает** (не заставляет залезать в консоль каждый раз).